# datagridview row font bold + mysql, .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I need help with my "messenger" app. All messages show in DGV. I need have "new messages" FontStyle.Bold. I compare logs and DGV and if spravaDGV !=spravaLOGY then DGV FontStyle.bold, but it not work

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {

       if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
       {
           DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

           citat.Text = "Správa od:  " + row.Cells["pc"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Dátum a čas:  " + row.Cells["datum"].Value.ToString()
               + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Správa:" + Environment.NewLine + row.Cells["sprava"].Value.ToString();
           spravaDGV = row.Cells["sprava"].Value.ToString();
           nacitanie_logu();
           zapisanie_logu();
           if (spravaDGV != spravaLOGY)
           {
               DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
               style.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
               dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle = style;
           }
       }

   }
```

inster into logs:

```
private void zapisanie_logu()
   {
       string constring = "Server=***;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;";
       string Query = "INSERT INTO OitDB.logy(pc,sprava)VALUES(@pc,@sprava)";
       MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
       MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
       cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprava", spravaDGV);
       cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", nazovPC);
       MySqlDataReader myReader;

       try
       {
           conDatabase.Open();
           myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
           MessageBox.Show("Správa odoslaná!");
           while (myReader.Read())
           {

           }

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

       }
   }
```

select from logs:

```
string spravaLOGY;
  private void nacitanie_logu()
  {
      MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("Server=***;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;");
      string s = "select sprava from logy where pc=@pc";
      mcon.Open();
      MySqlCommand mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, mcon);
      mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", nazovPC);
      MySqlDataReader mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();
      while (mdr.Read())
      {
          spravaLOGY = mdr.GetString("sprava");
      }
  }
```

insert, select and condition work good but change fontstyle not work. Have you any solution? Thx.

Comment: Change `dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle = style;` to `row.DefaultCellStyle = style;`

Comment: Still not work it ...

Comment: I think setting a default style will only work when the actual style is not set in the gridview. Try row.Style = style;

Comment: Now when I click to row change to bold, but I need have bold text and when I click to row change to normal. But only if spravaDGV=spravaLOGY